# How to fix Heroku Application Error after deploying

Tags: python, django, heroku

I need help with deploying this Django app.  My app name is `fixandflex`.

This is in my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn fixandflex.wsgi
```

LOGS:

```
heroku logs --tail --app desolate-woodland-37041
```

```
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160704+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160705+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160705+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160706+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160706+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160706+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160707+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160708+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160708+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixandflex.wsgi'
2020-02-09T15:18:12.160804+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:18:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-02-09T15:18:12.193506+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:18:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-02-09T15:18:12.193607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:18:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-02-09T15:18:12.262188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-02-09T15:19:06.178902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-09T15:19:05.740407+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fc360399 by user zameermuhammad92@gmail.com
2020-02-09T15:19:05.740407+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user zameermuhammad92@gmail.com
2020-02-09T15:19:16.335950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn fixandflex_second.wsgi`
2020-02-09T15:19:18.670920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-09T15:19:18.551099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-02-09T15:19:18.551795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3789 (4)
2020-02-09T15:19:18.551986+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-02-09T15:19:18.556611+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563459+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563472+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563486+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563487+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563487+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563487+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563487+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563491+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563492+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563493+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563493+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563493+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563493+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563494+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixandflex_second'
2020-02-09T15:19:18.563566+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-02-09T15:19:18.593216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-02-09T15:19:18.593311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:19:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-02-09T15:19:18.656623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-02-09T15:19:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-02-09T15:19:31.434964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-woodland-37041.herokuapp.com request_id=842fabd2-b89a-4fe5-86cf-d76502ca5e44 fwd="73.66.207.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-09T15:19:31.664094+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-woodland-37041.herokuapp.com request_id=b78b693c-c994-4289-8840-2e56341b6929 fwd="73.66.207.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-09T15:22:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user zameermuhammad92@gmail.com
2020-02-09T15:23:50.083832+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8e3c8092 by user zameermuhammad92@gmail.com
2020-02-09T15:23:50.083832+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user zameermuhammad92@gmail.com
2020-02-09T15:23:50.804460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-09T15:24:03.626633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn fixandflex.wsgi`
2020-02-09T15:24:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-02-09T15:24:07.228419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-09T15:24:07.210651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-02-09T15:24:07.056965+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-02-09T15:24:07.057955+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:33807 (4)
2020-02-09T15:24:07.058144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-02-09T15:24:07.065832+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078270+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078272+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078273+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078293+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078294+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078294+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078295+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078295+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078295+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078296+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078296+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078296+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078297+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078298+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078298+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078298+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078299+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078299+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078301+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixandflex.wsgi'
2020-02-09T15:24:07.078444+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-02-09T15:24:07.121010+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-02-09T15:24:07.121195+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-09 15:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

My directory structure can be seen in this very big image: [directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k3K.png)

Comment: Gunicorn can't find your WSGI module: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixandflex.wsgi'`. Please show us your directory structure.

Comment: I just added the screenshot of directory structure.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k3K.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to see in your screenshot, but it looks like the immediate problem is that you have an extra directory level:

- `.git/`
- `fixandflex/` ←

  - `fixandflex/`

    - `settings.py`
    - `wsgi.py`
    - `...`
  - `main/`

    - `...`
- `Pipfile`
- `Pipfile.lock`
- `...`

Generally everything inside your top-level `fixandflex/` directory would be in the root of your repository, beside your `.git/`, `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

You could do something like this from your top-level project directory:

```sh
mv fixandflex fixandflex-old
cd fixandflex-old
git mv fixandflex ..
cd ..
rmdir fixandflex
```

then commit and deploy.

If you don't want to do that, you may be able to get it working with your existing directory structure by modifying your `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn fixandflex.fixandflex.wsgi
```

Though if you do this you're going to have other issues. For example, you'll have to update your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and prepend another `fixandflex.` onto the front. And you'll probably have to do the same to any `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file. All in all, I recommend removing the extraneous directory.

Besides that issue, you also have a file called `requirement.txt` which is (a) not named conventionally (it's usually `requirements.txt` with an `s` on the end) and (b) not required or used by Heroku if you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. I recommend deleting it.

Additionally, I'm seeing a `db.sqlite3` file. If you're using SQLite you should know that this doesn't work well on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and [should not be used on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).

I *strongly* advise using the same database engine for local development and production. They are all subtly (and not-so-subtly) different, and you don't want to only find bugs once your code is in production. PostgreSQL is a common choice, and well-supported on Heroku, for example using [Heroku's own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres).

Comment: I changed the Procfile and deleted the requirements.txt file. its says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fixandflex.settings'

Comment: I still recommend the _first_ option, getting rid of that extra directory that doesn't do anything useful. That should "just work" (if you change your `Procfile` back). But you can try [setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `fixandflex.fixandflex.settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings), e.g. by running [`heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=fixandflex.fixandflex.settings`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Just bear in mind that there may also be other issues you run into going down this path.

Comment: If you keep that subdirectory you'll probably have to start referring to your `main` app as `fixandflex.main`, e.g. in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. There's probably more I'm not thinking about... if at all possible you should move your content up a directory as outlined in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Thnak you Chris, I'll try to change the sqlite3 to PostgreSQL. Then I'll redeploy

Comment: Hey Chris, I got it working by deleting the first fixandflex directory. THANK YOU SO MUCH.